# Need clarification on the near future of Flash

Tags: html, flash, frontend

I've been reading several articles on the web saying that Flash will no longer be supported. I'm a little bit confused about this: does it mean that Chrome / Firefox / IE etc will not run any Flash (swf) contents anymore? What happens with all the SWF files that are running at this very moment, will they stop showing?

Comment: AFAIK Adobe is going to discontinue the development of Flash platform in 2020. Browsers steadily move to "*Flash is supported but user have to explicitly allow it for each and every site*" policy. Thus if you target wide auditory rather than small group of devout users, you'll eventually have to move on to HTML5.

Comment: @Organis i see, so we should aim to the worst case scenario where flash will stop showing

Comment: Move on to HTML5.

Comment: @Organis got it

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know. I thought it meant they weren't going to update it anymore but hopefully, they don't stop using it because I have an entire website that runs off of flash.